# How is address arithmetic handled in NASM for x86 in hardware

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-architecture, addressing-mode

If I have an address in the rbx register and use an instruction like

```
mov rax, [rbx+1]
```

Is rbx+1 computed in hardware during runtime? If so are some registers used or is there a dedicated hardware piece?

I figured doing the same instruction but with a symbol instead of a register like so

```
string: db "I'm lost", 0

mov rax, [string+1]
```

would allow the calculation to be done at compile-time since it already has a location in memory reserved. Whereas rbx would be more variable and unknown until runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All CPUs, even original 8086, had some temporary buffers separate from the architectural registers. 8086 used the main ALU for address math, so `add ax, [bx + si + 1]` would need to use that temporary storage; the address math doesn't affect the software-visible value in the BX or RBX register.

Old CPUs like 8086 handled even simple x86 instructions by running a sequence of internal microcode instructions.  Modern CPUs decode an instruction like `mov eax, [rbx+1]` to a single micro-op (uop) for a load execution unit.  (They do still have buffering between pipeline stages, and even some temporary registers for instructions like `xchg eax, ecx` to use; on Intel that's a 3-uop instruction that's something like `mov internal_tmp, ecx` / `mov ecx, eax` / `mov eax, internal_tmp`.)

**Modern CPUs have dedicated address-generation units (AGUs) as part of load and store-address execution units, separate from their ALU execution units.** See https://realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/10 for a block diagram.

Related:

- [VIPT Cache: Connection between TLB & Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480015/vipt-cache-connection-between-tlb-cache) - describes the internal steps in a load execution unit.
- [Is Store Unit Also a Load Unit on an Intel processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051587/is-store-unit-also-a-load-unit-on-an-intel-processor) - talks some about the execution ports, although for it to make sense you probably already need to know the answer to this question and have read some of [Agner Fog's microarch guide](https://agner.org/optimize/).
- [Is there a penalty when base+offset is in a different page than the base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351397/is-there-a-penalty-when-baseoffset-is-in-a-different-page-than-the-base) - Intel CPUs before Ice Lake actually speculate about the `[rbx+1]` value being in the same page as `[rbx]`, if the `rbx` value is forwarded from another load.  This cuts down load-use latency for pointer-chasing (e.g. linked lists and binary trees) to 4 cycles vs. the usual 5, by letting TLB access start sooner.

Note that LEA is a separate animal; its result is written to a register, not used for load or store, so modern CPUs run it on an ALU execution unit as just a shift-and-add instruction.  (With some of the ALUs that support it not supporting the shift part, or only supporting one add, depending on the CPU model.  See [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers) - although this is true regardless of whether the integer value happens to a valid pointer or not.

Answer (score 2):

The operand `[rbx+1]` represents a valid addressing mode. If it wasn't, then your assembler would issue an error, because it would not know what to do with it, since it involves a register, whose value will only be known at runtime. Addressing modes are resolved at runtime by the hardware, and they never modify any registers other than the ones that are visible in the instruction.

The operand `[string+1]` is (as far as I know) ***not*** a valid addressing mode. But that is okay, because your assembler knows what to do with it: the address of `string` is known during assembly time, so the assembler uses that address plus one to compute the actual address, and replaces `[string+1]` with `[actual_address]`, which is a valid addressing mode. The assembler could, in theory, (and might in fact do in practice,) allow an entire expression in place of +1, and as long as the expression can be evaluated during assembly time, all is good.

The same would hold true with `[string+bx+1]`; strictly speaking, this is not a valid addressing mode, but the assembler knows how to combine all the offsets that are known at assembly time into just one offset, which results in `[computed_offset+bx]`, which is a valid addressing mode.

Comment: Correct, there isn't a machine-code encoding for adding two separate immediates because that would be pointless.  (Or in 64-bit mode, be a really inefficient way to have almost 33-bit absolute or relative addressing instead of the usual 32.)  As you say, this is what assemblers and linkers are for, letting us write convenient symbol + number and compute a displacement for the machine code.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for confirming. I feel obliged to explain why I added an answer despite the fact that you had already posted an answer: I think that your answers show very deep knowledge of the subject, and they are technically perfect, (as far as I can tell, with my limited knowledge,) but they are written in a language which is probably waaaay beyond the vocabulary and level of comprehension of most readers.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for writing up a simpler version.  I upvoted this.  I didn't spend a lot of effort on my answer making it beginner-friendly and I didn't really know where to start to introduce the complexities or address all the misconceptions the question might have had; it was almost going to be a comment linking a few things like https://realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge and http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/.  Definitely the the kind of question that can benefit from multiple answers explaining things in different ways and from different perspectives.